# solrj RealTime get

Tags: solr, solrj

How can I execute a [RealTime get](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/RealTimeGet) request from the SolrJ client?

I specifically need to retrieve un-commited documents in order to check the `_version_` field for [optimistic concurrency](http://yonik.com/solr/optimistic-concurrency/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the RealTime Get is implemented with an alternate requestHandler, you would just need to use the `setRequestHandler()` method on `SolrQuery` passing `"/get"` as the handler name.

Please see the `testRealTimeGet()` method in this [SolrExampleTests.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/solrj/src/test/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrExampleTests.java?view=markup) file from the Solr source for a full example.

Here is the snippet from that file:

```
  SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery();
  q.setRequestHandler("/get");
  q.set("id", "DOCID");
  q.set("fl", "id,name,aaa:[value v=aaa]");
```